# How to change the option label in vuejs laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am learning VUE and cannot figure out how to change the label of options in select.

I have this array which I sent from Controller to view.

```
 previewData
 0=>[
    'label' => 'abc',
    'width' => 123,
    'height' => 432
]
1=>[
    'label' => 'abc',
    'width' => 123,
    'height' => 432
]
```

this is my code

```
  import vSelect     from 'vue-select';
export default {
    props     : [
        'preview_size',
    ],
    data      : () => {
        return {
            previewData     : [],
            assetData       : {id: 0, name: '', parent_id: '', nameError: '', maintain_version: true},

            selectedItem    : {},
            selectedPreview : null,
            scalePreview    : false,
            selectedSection : {},
            selectedBlocks  : {},
            versionchange   : null,
            previousVersion : null,
            previousSections: [],
            losses          : [],
            previewLink     : '',
            instantDownload : false,
            tags            : [],
            selectedTags    : [],
            selectedElements: [],
        };
    },
    created() {
        this.previewData  = JSON.parse(this.preview_size);
    components: {
        uuid,
        vSelect,
    });


<v-select
                class='form-control col-md-8'
                v-model='selectedPreview'
                :options='previewData'
                data-error='Please correct this field.'
            />
```

I cannot figure out how to change the label it shows like this

```
<option>abc</option>
<option>abc</option>
```

I want to show it like this

```
<option>abc 123 x 432</option>
<option>abc 123 x 432</option>
```

What I tried

```
<v-select
                class='form-control col-md-8'
                v-model='selectedPreview'
                :options='previewData'
                data-error='Please correct this field.'
                <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
                  <span :class="option.label"></span>
                  {{ option.width }}px x {{ option.height }}px {{ option.label }}
                </template>
            />
```

But still shows the label only.

Comment: Sounds like you will want to use a computed property to format the `previewData` and pass the computed property as the `options` to the select component.

Comment: That does sound right.

Comment: You mean `previewData` ?

Comment: Yess,  `import vSelect     from 'vue-select';`

Comment: Something [like this](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ERmQRG?editors=1010).

Comment: You can create a new attribute `fullLabel` (which concatenates your label, width and height) and add to your `v-select` declaration `label="fullLabel"` (https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Basics/Options.html)